# Redirect Loop Issue on Logout Button Click Laravel 5.2.15

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**My Routes are like below**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/Roles', array('uses' => 'RoleController@Roles', 'as' => 'Roles'));
});
```

After successful authentiaction, I can see list of roles and there is logout button. Clicking on Logout button goes to `class RedirectIfAuthenticated`.

We have handle method in this class

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

It goes inside if condition and here issue is coming.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AuthController Constructor should be like below and issue got fixed.

```
public function __construct()
{
    //$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The AuthController by default puts the guest middleware on all methods except `logout`. Your route is going to `getLogout`. Adjust the middleware declaration in the AuthController or adjust your route to use the default method `logout`.